# How do we compute Hodge duals?

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, electromagnetism

The motivation for this question is to try to come up with a general expression for $(\star F)_{\mu\nu}$, the $\mu,\nu$ component of the Hodge dual of the [Field strength tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_tensor), which is of great importance in Electrodynamics. In the course I am taking, the instructor has defined it *contravariantly*, as
$$(\star F)^{\mu\nu}=\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}F_{\alpha\beta}$$
Where $F_{\alpha\beta}$ are the components of the normal field strength tensor,
$$F_{\alpha\beta}=\nabla_\alpha A_\beta-\nabla_\beta A_\alpha$$
And we have defined the raised Levi-Civita symbol using the [generalized Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta#Generalizations):
$$\varepsilon^{ijkl}=\delta^{i~j~k~l}_{1~2~3~4}$$
However, there are some problems with this equation. As far as I know, it only holds when the metric is simple as possible, i.e $\boldsymbol{\eta}=\operatorname{diag}(-1,1,1,1)$ the standard Minkowski metric. I don't think it holds in other coordinate systems e.g polar coordinates. Also, I thought the Hodge star was a map that took $k$ forms to $d-k$ forms, where $d$ is the dimension of the space. But my instructor's equation seems to have the Hodge dual being a fully contravariant tensor... are the components he is listing actually the components of $(\star\mathbf{F})^{\sharp}$, its index-raised counterpart?

With this motivation, I searched the internet for answers and stumbled across [this post on physics SE.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/524042/dual-tensor-in-electrodynamics) Given a $d$ dimensional manifold, the author of the post defines the Hodge dual of a totally skew-symmetric $k$ form $\omega$ as having components

$$(\star \omega)_{\mu_1\dots\mu_{d-k}}=\frac{1}{k!}\epsilon^{\nu_1\dots\nu_k}{}_{\mu_1\dots\mu_{d-k}}\omega_{\nu_1\dots\nu_k}$$

---

However, the author does not make it very clear what the object $\epsilon^{\nu_1\dots\nu_k}{}_{\mu_1\dots\mu_{d-k}}$ is. He does write
$$\epsilon_{\mu_1\dots\mu_d}=\sqrt{-g}~\varepsilon_{\mu_1\dots\mu_d}$$
But not only does this look *very* different to$\epsilon^{\nu_1\dots\nu_k}{}_{\mu_1\dots\mu_{d-k}}$ in terms of the number and structure of the indices, it also raises other concerns, like what if $g=\det \mathbf{g}$ is a positive number? Will we start getting imaginary components of the Hodge dual, even when we are working on a real manifold?

**My request:** Could someone please provide some other formula for the Hodge dual of a totally skew symmetric $k$ form on a $d$ dimensional manifold, in terms of well known objects, such as the metric, Christoffel symbols, Kronecker delta, Levi-Civita symbol, etc? I searched the Wikipedia page for answers but I found it very dense and difficult to understand.

Comment: Does this help?  It gives you an alternate perspective. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/162366/distributing-the-hodge-map-over-the-wedge-product/165524#165524

Comment: Looks like the components are those of $(\star F)^\sharp$. For the generalized Kroneckar, did you mean something like $\delta_{1234}^{ijkl}$?  The expression involving $g$ is $\sqrt{|\det(g)|}$, no imaginary units are present. The Levi-Civita *symbol* has the same components in any co-ordinate system. To construct the Levi-Civita *tensor*, note $\epsilon^{\text{tensor}}_{ij\dots}=\sqrt{|g|}\varepsilon^{\text{symbol}}_{ij\dots}$. The expression in your post for Hodge dual is correct, and includes a mixture of up/ down indices on the Levi-Civita tensor, which may be raised using the metric

Comment: @Sal yes, I did mean 1234... i will correct it. If it is supposed to be $\sqrt{|g|}$, why do I see so many people write $\sqrt{-g}$?

Comment: @Sal So are you suggesting that $$\epsilon^{\nu_1\dots\nu_k}{}_{\mu_1\dots\mu_{d-k}}=\sqrt{|g|}\varepsilon^{\nu_1\dots\nu_k}{}_{\mu_1\dots\mu_{d-k}} \\=\sqrt{|g|}g^{\alpha_1 \nu_1}\dots g^{\alpha_k\nu_k}\varepsilon_{\alpha_1\dots\alpha_k~\mu_1\dots\mu_{d-k}}$$
?

Comment: Yes, [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Levi-Civita_tensors) is precisely what I'm suggesting. I guess it's often written as $\sqrt{-g}$ because in 3+1 dimensions the determinant is necessarily negative... and it makes equations look impressively complex?

Comment: @Sal Thank you! You are a real lifesaver. This makes everything so much more clear. If you would summarize everything in an answer, I would accept it so as to mark this query as resolved.

Comment: No problem; I'm glad it was helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Hodge dual maps $k$ forms to $n-k$ forms, and *covariant* skew-symmetric tensors are forms, the contravariant expression for $(\star F)$ must be interpreted as $(\star F)^\sharp$.

The expression for Hodge dual in OP is correct. What appears on the RHS is the [Levi-Civita tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol#Levi-Civita_tensors), with a mixture of up/ down indices. The Levi-Civita symbol, which has the same components in all co-ordinates, is related to it by

$$
\epsilon^{\text{tensor}}_{ij\dots}=\sqrt{|g|}\varepsilon^{\text{symbol}}_{ij\dots}
$$

Since this is a tensor, indices may be raised and lowered with the metric as necessary

$$
\epsilon^{\nu_1\dots\nu_k}{}_{\mu_1\dots\mu_{d-k}}=\sqrt{|g|}g^{\alpha_1 \nu_1}\dots g^{\alpha_k\nu_k}\varepsilon_{\alpha_1\dots\alpha_k~\mu_1\dots\mu_{d-k}}
$$

The expression $\sqrt{-g}$ is more generally $\sqrt{|\det(g)|}$. In Lorentz spacetime the determinant is necessarily negative so there is no harm (and no imaginary units) in writing $\sqrt{-g}$.

References: *Spacetime and geometry* by S. Carrol.