# Prove basis independence of determinant with Levi-Civita symbol

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

Let $V$ be an $N$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, and $A$ a linear operator on it. Choose a basis $\{e_i\}$ of $V$, under which $A$ is represented by the matrix ${A^i}_j$ (upper/lower indices transform [contravariantly/covariantly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_of_vectors) with basis changes), i.e. the image of $e_j$ is

$$
A e_j = e_i {A^i}_j
$$

We define the determinant of $A$ as

$$
\det A = \frac{1}{N!} 
\epsilon_{i_1 ... i_N}
\epsilon^{j_1 ... j_N}
{A^{i_1}}_{j_1} \cdots {A^{i_N}}_{j_N}
$$

Here both $\epsilon_{i_1 ... i_N}$ (with all lower indices) and $\epsilon^{j_1 ... j_N}, $ (with all upper indices) are Levi-Civita symbols. But these "symbols" does not change with basis changes. The index positions of $\epsilon$ does not have special meanings; they are written simply to comply with tensor analysis ([Ricci calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_calculus)) rules: we sum over paired upper/lower indices.

In usual tensor analysis, if an expression does not contain unpaired (free) upper/lower indices, then it is invariant under a basis change. But here the Levi-Civita symbols are, strictly speaking, *not* tensors (it only *behaves like* a tensor under *orthogonal* basis changes, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2228996/882595) Math.SE question). How to start from this definition of $\det A$ to show that it is basis independent?

Comment: As shown by Sal in his answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4325777/how-do-we-compute-hodge-duals), you can make the Levi-Civita symbol tensorial by adjusting it with a prefactor. Letting $\epsilon$ be the Levi-Civita symbol, you can define the Levi-Civita **tensor** $\varepsilon$ as 
$$\varepsilon_{i_1\dots i_n}=\sqrt{|g|}\epsilon_{i_1\dots i_n}$$
Where $g$ is the metric.

Comment: @K.defaoite What if the vector space $V$ does not have a metric?

Comment: Good point. Let me think about that.

Comment: How about first proving the product rule?

Comment: Correction: $Ae_j=A^i{}_ke^k_j$, not $e_iA^i{}_j$. Note that $e_iA^i{}_j=e_1A^1{}_j+\dots +e_nA^n{}_j$ which is not the same thing as $Ae_j$.

Comment: @K.defaoite Indices on LHS in your correction do not match RHS. My $A e_j$ is actually $A(e_j)$.

Comment: @blargoner Well that's indeed a solution.